# Error: Unknown provider: SessionProvider <- Session AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, devise

I am aware that the error which is in the title of this question is basically because in my controller I am injecting a Session service in my controller that has not been defined. I am currently looking at: [Angular Devise](https://github.com/vfonic/Angular-Devise-Todolist) for which I am rolling out in an application that is using rails but have angular and rails separate. My setup on the angular side is as followed:

**main.js**

```
angular.module('App.controllers', []);
angular.module('App.config', []);
angular.module('App.directives', [])
angular.module('App.resources', ['ngResource']);
angular.module('App.services', []);

var App = angular.module("App", [
  "ngResource",
  "ngCookies",
  "$strap.directives",
  "App.services",
  "App.directives",
  "App.resources",
  "App.controllers",
  "TotemApp.config"
  ], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
  var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function (scope, $q) {
      function success(response) {
          return response;
      }

      function error(response) {
          var status = response.status;

          if (status == 401) {
              window.location = "/login";
              return;
          }
          return $q.reject(response);

      }

      return function (promise) {
          return promise.then(success, error);
      }
  }];
});
```

**Session.js**

```
App.service('Session',[ '$cookieStore', 'UserSession', 'UserRegistration', function($cookieStore, UserSession, UserRegistration) {

  this.currentUser = function() {
    return $cookieStore.get('_angular_devise_user');
  }
  this.signedIn = function() {
    return !!this.currentUser();
  }
  this.signedOut = function() {
    return !this.signedIn();
  }
  this.userSession = new UserSession( { email:"sample@email.com", password:"password", remember_me:true } );
  this.userRegistration = new UserRegistration( { email:"sample@email.com", password:"password", password_confirmation:"password" } );
}]);
```

**sessions_controller**

```
App.controller('SessionsController', ['$scope', '$location', '$cookieStore', 'Session', function($scope, $location, $cookieStore, Session) {

  $scope.session = Session.userSession;

  $scope.create = function() {

    if ( Session.signedOut ) {
      $scope.session.$save().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $cookieStore.put('_angular_devise_user', Session.userSession.email);
        $location.path('/todos');
      });
    }
  };

  $scope.destroy = function() {
    $cookieStore.remove('_angular_devise_user');
    $scope.session.$destroy();
  };

}]);
```

**routes.js**

'use strict';

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sessions/new.html',
        controller: 'SessionsController'
      })
      .when('/sign_up', {
        templateUrl: 'views/registrations/new.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationsController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    });
```

This error occurs when I try to access the login page or register page. If someone can shed some light that would be greatly appreciated. Not entirely sure how to resolve this `Error: Unknown provider: $SessionProvider <- $Session` error

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this looks correct.  I can only assume that perhaps you've not included Session.js in your index.html file?

Angular clearly doesn't know what 'Session' service is so there's something wrong there either file not loaded, not loaded correctly or something along those lines as far as I can see.

Edit: Does the error say 'SessionProvider <- Session' or '$SessionProvider -< $session'  because if it's the latter, then something is named wrong somewhere in your app since your service is named 'Session' not '$Session'.

Comment: This is the output in the console window: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6668605 and I also agree with your first comment that perhaps it weren't included. Inddeed I saw a similar post here: https://plus.google.com/107290594765463806793/posts/hh8KJb1qWTx that suggested the same thing. I did try this and had no look.

Comment: Right so somewhere in my app I have named it $Session and not `Session`

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is incorrect as such but your app.js appears to be missing .config().  You've got an array of dependencies inside your module() call and then go straight to a function within the module call.  As far as I'm aware you need to end module() and do a .config() call and contain the function in there (or .run).  But perhaps this is a shorthand I'm not aware of.  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Right okay solved that and now have a circular dependency issue. X_X

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be called `main.js`

Comment: I've wired up my `config()` to sit in another file under `routes.js`. Which you'll see from my update

Comment: The issue is somewhat solved, but I am getting: `Error: Unknown provider: UserSessionProvider <- UserSession <- Session`

Answer (score 0):

When you have syntax error in other javascript or typescript files. You will get the same error. Please make sure that you have no syntax error.